# How to open another URL in a different window when a html page is loaded?

Tags: html

I have one html page, with a form on it. When the user posts the form, I want the form receiving the response to automatically open up the URL passed by the post in a new browser window.

Basically the URL is passed to the the other page, which in turn opens the URL in a new window then displays another form.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 1):

Add `target="_blank"` attribute to the `<form>`.

```
<form action="http://google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This will show the response in a new (blank) window. Note that this happens *before* the HTML page is loaded (it wouldn't make much sense otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will put a new form on the page receiving the post action. What I need is to receive the URL posted to the form receiving the action and then automatically opening up a new browser window using the URL received by the form. I do not want the user to have to click submit query. I want the URL automaically opened in a new browser window.

Comment: @Shane, what you're asking does not make sense. BalusC's answer is the best you can do.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly. I have page1 with a URL on it. When the user clicks the URL I want to perform a post with an action to another html page2. This html page2 in turn opens up the URL received from the form post on html page1 in a new browser window and displays a input form on html page2.

Comment: Basically I want to force the opening of a URL in a new broswers window when a html page is loaded for the first time and not as a popup, but in a new browser window.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are doing. On Page1, you have a link with a URL that you want the user to click on, which opens a new window that fetches the URL that the user clicked on. Is that correct? Something like <a href="javascript:window.open('/foo.html?url.com')">foo.html</a>